Azure API Management Importing Versioned Open Api
We are trying to import already versioned Open API documents in to Azure API Management. There are two Open API documents, one for v1 and other for v2. When using Azure API management versioning, it adds additional v1/v2 in the route path. Something like below
https://dev.test.com/testAPI/tryv1/**v1/v1**/examples/{exampleId}

Our Open APIs already have v1/v2 in their paths. So, we do not want to get default versioning in the path from Azure APIM.
example of open api document of v1 file (I did not paste the whole file instead pasted a part of it):
{
  "x-generator": "NSwag v13.16.0.0 (NJsonSchema v10.7.1.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0))",
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "Test v1",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "https://localhost:234"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "**/v1/**support/examples": {

example of open api document of v2 file: (I did not paste the whole file instead pasted a part of it):
{
  "x-generator": "NSwag v13.16.0.0 (NJsonSchema v10.7.1.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0))",
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "Test v2",
    "version": "2.0.0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "https://localhost:234"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "**/v2/**support/examples": {

How to import these files in azure api management using versioning and do not allow APIM to add versions to it?
Currently we are importing these files in to 2 separate APIs in azure apim  so that azure apim do not add versioning to it.
Thanks in advance,

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63263394/azure-api-management-versioning-path-schema-duplicates-version-in-url. Its better not to add the path in swagger as apim will add it
